# Socket programming, multithreaded game, getting an End Of File Exception

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I'm trying to implement a little game, where multiple clients have to connect to a server, and play together. Every one has a different GUI and they communicate through the class ClientConnect, which is a Runnable started from the GUI class. The problem is that i'm getting an EOFException at the first lines of code, when i'm trying to intanciate the inputstream. The server is of course started at the beginning and sending an object. 
Here is a cut of the implementation where i get the exception.

What should i do?

```
 public ClientConnect(InetAddress address, int port) throws IOException {
    clientSock = new Socket(address, port);             
}

@Override
public void run() {
    ArrayList<Object> receivedObject = null;
    try (ObjectInputStream fromServer = new ObjectInputStream(clientSock.getInputStream());
            ObjectOutputStream toServer = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSock.getOutputStream()))
        {
            while(!move) {
                receivedObject = (ArrayList<Object>) fromServer.readObject();
                move = !(receivedObject.get(0).equals("you have to wait!!"));
            }

            actualPlayer = (String) receivedObject.get(0);
            scoreCard = (List<String>) receivedObject.get(1);           
            highScore = (HashMap<String, Integer>) receivedObject.get(2);
            numberOfPlayers = (int) receivedObject.get(3);          
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
 CShellExt::CShelljava.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at edu.hm.se2.kniffel.ClientConnect.run(ClientConnect.java:41)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Ext()
```

The line 41 is the line with the try

I'm starting the ClientConnect thread in the GUI like that:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            //Online-Spiel starten
            if(game.listLength()>0){
                try {
                    client = new ClientConnect(InetAddress.getByName(null), 2000);
                    new Thread(client).start();
                    while (!client.getMove()) {
                        lblActualUser.setText("WAITING.... " + client.getActualPlayer() + " ist an der Reihe");
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

I Got something blocking the serversocket to be opened!

Comment: Your explanation is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

On this evidence, the peer isn't creating an `ObjectOutputStream` at all, it's just connecting and then closing the socket.

You should construct the `ObjectOutputStream` before the `ObjectInputStream`, at both ends.